# mobile OpenCL local memory bank conflict. Why using local memory is slower than does global memory in kernel?

Tags: android, opencl, viola-jones, bank-conflict

I'm developing face detection app in android platform using `OpenCL`. Face detection algorithm is based on Viola Jones algorithm. I tried to make Cascade classification step kernel code. and I set `classifier data` of cascade stage 1 among cascade stages  to `local memory(__local)` because classifier data are used for all work-items.

But, kernel profiling time without using local mem(using global mem) is more faster than that does with using local memory.

edited :

I uploaded full code.

---

with local memory version

```
__kernel void CASCADE(__read_only image2d_t input_image, __write_only image2d_t output_image,__constant float* classifierMem,__constant int* idxNumValStageArray, int numTotStage, __constant int* vecSkin){
       int cascadeLocalSize = get_local_size(0);

       __local float localS1F1[42];

       int localIdx = get_local_id(1)*cascadeLocalSize + get_local_id(0);
       if(localIdx<42)
       {
           int stage1Idx = localIdx + idxNumValStageArray[0]+4;
           localS1F1[localIdx] = classifierMem[stage1Idx];
       }
       barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);


       float resizeFactor = 1.0;
       int2 im_dim = get_image_dim(input_image);
       unsigned int srcWidth = im_dim.x*(float)resizeFactor;
       unsigned int srcHeight = im_dim.y*(float)resizeFactor;

       int gx = get_global_id(0);
       int gy = get_global_id(1);

       int skinX=0;
       int skinY=0;
       int coordi=vecSkin[512*gy+gx];
       skinX = coordi%im_dim.x;
       skinY = coordi/im_dim.x;

       if( skinX >= 10 && skinY >= 10 )
       {
             skinX -= 10;
             skinY -= 10;
       }      

       int type = gx%3;

       unsigned int windowWidth = classifierMem[0];
       unsigned int windowHeight = classifierMem[1]; 


       unsigned int stageIndex;
       float stageThres;
       float numFeatures;
       unsigned int featureIndex;
       float featureValue;

       if(skinX<srcWidth-windowWidth-1 && skinY<srcHeight-windowHeight-1){
             bool stagePass = true;
             unsigned int index = 0;
             for(unsigned int i=numTotStage; i>0;i--){
                    if(stagePass){
                           if(index == 0){
                                 stageIndex = idxNumValStageArray[0];                                 
                                 stageThres = classifierMem[stageIndex+2];
                                 numFeatures = classifierMem[stageIndex+3];
                                 featureIndex = 0;
                                 featureValue = 0.0;                           
                           }
                           else{
                                 stageIndex = idxNumValStageArray[index];
                                 stageThres = classifierMem[stageIndex+2];
                                 numFeatures = classifierMem[stageIndex+3];
                                 featureIndex = stageIndex+4;
                                 featureValue = 0.0;
                           }
                           float featureThres;
                           float succVal;
                           float failVal;
                           unsigned int numRegions;
                           float regionValue;


                           if(type ==0 && index==0)
                           {
                                 for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--){
                                        if(stagePass){
                                               featureThres=localS1F1[featureIndex++]*(windowWidth*windowHeight);
                                              succVal=localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              failVal=localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              numRegions = localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              regionValue =0.0;

                                              float4 rectValue;
                                              int4 regionP;                                  
                                              for(unsigned int k=numRegions; k>0;k--){

                                                     regionP.x=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex])+skinX;
                                                     regionP.y=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+1])+skinY;
                                                     regionP.z=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+2])+regionP.x;
                                                     regionP.w=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+3])+regionP.y;

                                                     rectValue.x = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xy).x;
                                                     rectValue.y = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zy).x;
                                                     rectValue.z = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xw).x;
                                                     rectValue.w = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zw).x;

                                                     regionValue += dot(rectValue, (float4)(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f))*localS1F1[featureIndex+4];

                                                     featureIndex+=5;
                                              }
                                              featureValue += (regionValue < featureThres)?failVal:succVal;                              
                                              if(j*2 == (unsigned int)numFeatures && featureValue*2 < stageThres) stagePass =false;

                                        }// end of if(stagePass) 
                                 }// end of for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--)

                                  index++;
                                 if(featureValue < stageThres)    stagePass =false;
                                 else if(index==numTotStage) write_imagef(output_image, (int2)(skinX, skinY), (0.1));

                           }

                           else if(type ==1 && index ==0)
                           {
                                 featureIndex +=14;
                                 for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--){
                                        if(stagePass){
                                              if(j==1)
                                                     featureIndex -= 42;

                                               featureThres=localS1F1[featureIndex++]*(windowWidth*windowHeight);
                                              succVal=localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              failVal=localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              numRegions = localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              regionValue =0.0;


                                              float4 rectValue;
                                              int4 regionP;                                  
                                              for(unsigned int k=numRegions; k>0;k--){

                                                     regionP.x=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex])+skinX;
                                                     regionP.y=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+1])+skinY;
                                                     regionP.z=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+2])+regionP.x;
                                                     regionP.w=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+3])+regionP.y;

                                                     rectValue.x = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xy).x;
                                                     rectValue.y = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zy).x;
                                                     rectValue.z = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xw).x;
                                                     rectValue.w = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zw).x;

                                                     regionValue += dot(rectValue, (float4)(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f))*localS1F1[featureIndex+4];

                                                     featureIndex+=5;
                                              }
                                              featureValue += (regionValue < featureThres)?failVal:succVal;                              
                                              if(j*2 == (unsigned int)numFeatures && featureValue*2 < stageThres) stagePass =false;
                                        }
                                 }

                                  index++;
                                 if(featureValue < stageThres)    stagePass =false;
                                 else if(index==numTotStage) write_imagef(output_image, (int2)(skinX, skinY), (0.1));
                           }

                           else if(index == 0)
                           {
                                 featureIndex +=28;
                                 for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--){
                                        if(stagePass){

                                              if(j==2)     featureIndex -= 42;

                                               featureThres=localS1F1[featureIndex++]*(windowWidth*windowHeight);
                                              succVal=localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              failVal=localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              numRegions = localS1F1[featureIndex++];
                                              regionValue =0.0;

                                              float4 rectValue;
                                              int4 regionP;                                  
                                              for(unsigned int k=numRegions; k>0;k--){

                                                     regionP.x=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex])+skinX;
                                                     regionP.y=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+1])+skinY;
                                                     regionP.z=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+2])+regionP.x;
                                                     regionP.w=(int)(localS1F1[featureIndex+3])+regionP.y;

                                                     rectValue.x = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xy).x;
                                                     rectValue.y = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zy).x;
                                                     rectValue.z = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xw).x;
                                                     rectValue.w = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zw).x;

                                                     regionValue += dot(rectValue, (float4)(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f))*localS1F1[featureIndex+4];

                                                     featureIndex+=5;
                                              }// end of for(unsigned int k=numRegions; k>0;k--)
                                              featureValue += (regionValue < featureThres)?failVal:succVal;                              
                                              if(j*2 == (unsigned int)numFeatures && featureValue*2 < stageThres) stagePass =false;

                                        }// end of if(stagePass)
                                 }//end of for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--)

                                 index++;
                                 if(featureValue < stageThres)    stagePass =false;
                                 else if(index==numTotStage) write_imagef(output_image, (int2)(skinX, skinY), (0.1));
                           }

                           //stage 
                           else{
                                 for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--){
                                        if(stagePass){
                                               featureThres=classifierMem[featureIndex++]*(windowWidth*windowHeight);
                                              succVal=classifierMem[featureIndex++];
                                              failVal=classifierMem[featureIndex++];
                                              numRegions = classifierMem[featureIndex++];
                                              regionValue =0.0;
                                              float4 rectValue;
                                              int4 regionP;                                  
                                              for(unsigned int k=numRegions; k>0;k--){
                                                     regionP.x=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex])+skinX;
                                                     regionP.y=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex+1])+skinY;
                                                     regionP.z=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex+2])+regionP.x;
                                                     regionP.w=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex+3])+regionP.y;
                                                     rectValue.x = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xy).x;
                                                     rectValue.y = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zy).x;
                                                     rectValue.z = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xw).x;
                                                     rectValue.w = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zw).x;
                                                     regionValue += dot(rectValue, (float4)(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f))*classifierMem[featureIndex+4]; 
                                                     featureIndex+=5;
                                              }
                                              featureValue += (regionValue < featureThres)?failVal:succVal;                              
                                              if(j*2 == (unsigned int)numFeatures && featureValue*2 < stageThres) stagePass =false;
                                        }
                                 }
                                 index++;
                                 if(featureValue < stageThres)    stagePass =false;
                                 else if(index==numTotStage) write_imagef(output_image, (int2)(skinX, skinY), (0.1));
                           }
                    }
             }      
       }else return;
}
```

---

original version(without local mem)

```
__kernel void CASCADE(__read_only image2d_t input_image, __write_only image2d_t output_image,__constant float* classifierMem,__constant int* idxNumValStageArray, int numTotStage, __constant int* vecSkin){
    float resizeFactor = 1.0;

    int2 im_dim = get_image_dim(input_image);

    unsigned int srcWidth = im_dim.x*(float)resizeFactor;
    unsigned int srcHeight = im_dim.y*(float)resizeFactor;

    int gx = get_global_id(0);
    int gy = get_global_id(1);


    int skinX=0;
    int skinY=0;
    int coordi=vecSkin[512*gy+gx];
    skinX = coordi%im_dim.x;
    skinY = coordi/im_dim.x;

        if( skinX >= 10 && skinY >= 10 )
    {
        skinX -= 10;
        skinY -= 10;
    }   

    unsigned int windowWidth = classifierMem[0];
    unsigned int windowHeight = classifierMem[1];   

    if(gx<srcWidth-windowWidth-1 && gy<srcHeight-windowHeight-1){
        bool stagePass = true;
        unsigned int index = 0;
        for(unsigned int i=numTotStage; i>0;i--){
            if(stagePass){
                unsigned int stageIndex = idxNumValStageArray[index++];
                float stageThres = classifierMem[stageIndex+2];
                float numFeatures = classifierMem[stageIndex+3];
                unsigned int featureIndex = stageIndex+4;
                float featureValue = 0.0;               

                for(unsigned int j=numFeatures; j>0;j--){
                    if(stagePass){
                        float featureThres=classifierMem[featureIndex++]*(windowWidth*windowHeight);
                        float succVal=classifierMem[featureIndex++];
                        float failVal=classifierMem[featureIndex++];
                        unsigned int numRegions = classifierMem[featureIndex++];
                        float regionValue =0.0;

                        for(unsigned int k=numRegions; k>0;k--){                    
                            float4 rectValue;
                            int4 regionP;

                            regionP.x=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex])+skinX;
                            regionP.y=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex+1])+skinY;
                            regionP.z=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex+2])+regionP.x;
                            regionP.w=(int)(classifierMem[featureIndex+3])+regionP.y;

                            rectValue.x = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xy).x;
                            rectValue.y = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zy).x;
                            rectValue.z = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.xw).x;
                            rectValue.w = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, regionP.zw).x;

                            regionValue += dot(rectValue, (float4)(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f))*classifierMem[featureIndex+4];

                            featureIndex+=5;
                        }

                        featureValue += (regionValue < featureThres)?failVal:succVal;                   

                        if(j*2 == (unsigned int)numFeatures && featureValue*2 < stageThres) stagePass =false;
                    }
                }
                if(featureValue < stageThres)   stagePass =false;
                else if(index==numTotStage) write_imagef(output_image, (int2)(skinX, skinY), (0.1));
            }
        }   
    }else return;
}
```

---

profiling time : 
original version(without local mem) : 24ms
modified version(with local mem) : 28ms

edited :
actually localWorkSize NULL becasue globalWorkSize always vary by vector size which put the NDRangeKernel. When Put the specific localWorkSize, face detection rate fall... So i tried to put the localWorkSize NUll, then face detection rate good. So I want to the reason.

this is host code :

```
    //localWorkSize[0] = 16;
    //localWorkSize[1] = 12; 
    numThreadsX=512;
    globalWorkSize[0] = numThreadsX;
    globalWorkSize[1] =  vecCoordinate.size()% numThreadsX == 0 ? vecCoordinate.size()/ numThreadsX :(vecCoordinate.size()/ numThreadsX) + 1;
    errNum = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue,classifierMem,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float)*cntValArray,stageValArray,0,NULL,NULL); 
    errNum |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue,idxStageMem,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*haar.numStages,idxNumValStageArray,0,NULL,NULL); 
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kHaar_Cascade, 0, sizeof(memObjBuffer_Haar22), &memObjBuffer_Haar22);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kHaar_Cascade, 1, sizeof(memObjBuffer22), &memObjBuffer22);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kHaar_Cascade, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &classifierMem);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kHaar_Cascade, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &idxStageMem);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kHaar_Cascade, 4, sizeof(cl_int), &haar.numStages);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kHaar_Cascade, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), &memVecCoordi);

    errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kHaar_Cascade, 2, NULL,globalWorkSize, NULL,0, NULL, &event[3]);
```

Comment: What device are you running this on?

Comment: Then lower the work group size to increase max local per thread

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't understand yor comment. What's meaning " to increate max local"??

Comment: If there were 256 threads per compute unit, when you decrese it to 64 you quadruple available memory amount per thread.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik My problem is not local mem size but when I use more local mem, profiling time is slower than without using local memory only global memory version :(
When i test using a variety of local mem size, The more local mem i used, the slower profiling time is.

Comment: please indicate how much slower it is - preferably also list ms for each version

Comment: @youngwanlee indicate the workgroup sizes too

Comment: @youngwanlee please remember to select an answer and to upvote it. Also, unless you provide workgroup sizes we can't get any more specific but I am confident in the reasons I supplied.

Comment: @JasonNewton actually localWorkSize NULL becasue globalWorkSize always vary by vector size which put the NDRangeKernel. When Put the specific localWorkSize, face detection rate fall... So i tried to put the localWorkSize NUll, then face detection rate good. So I want to the reason.

Comment: you might determine what the local work size is by printing from the kernel with printf

Comment: @JasonNewton I can't printf because of this implementation is on a smart phone

Comment: there are other ways to do that...save it to another global buffer, and print it after the kernel sets it?  anyway while I am curious to know i don't think the answer is going to affect the conclusion/answers below.

Comment: @JasonNewton this Cascade kernel recommend workGroupSize is 192(CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE) 
after print localWorkSize, it shows (128,1),(128,1) (8,17), (2,67),(2,67),(32,5), (64,3),(64,3),(64,3),(128,1),(64,3),(64,3),(64,3),(128,1),(128,1),(128,1),(128,1),(128,1),(32,5),(128,1),(64,3),(128,1),(128,1).....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a variety of reasons:

- Thread divergence of the memory load
- Barriers aren't free
- More instructions
- On most platforms constant memory is pretty much the same as shared memory, so the extra work has no gains.
- We don't know how many reads the shared memory version is saving - please tell us the size of the work group.  The smaller it is, the less reads from non-local memory we are saving.  Not that it matters if this is constant memory.

Profile both of them and see if the profiler's outputs shows anything at max utilization of anything and indicate to us what that is.

Also, I'm not convinced your localIdx and stage1Idx make sense, they could be going out of array bounds and causing odd behaviors.  At the very least for a given gx/gy you look like you're using different indices from classifierMem.

Answer (score 0):

You have five floating point values (20 bytes) that are being read by every work-item. Most modern GPUs will have hardware-managed caches that sit at a similar level in the memory hierarchy to user-managed local memory. In your version that doesn't use local memory, these 20 bytes will quite happily sit in a cache close to the ALUs, and deliver all of the data-reuse performance benefits you could hope for. Your version that uses local memory is just doing the same thing explicitly, but also adds a bunch of extra overhead to manually initiate the copies and some extra synchronisation between work-items, which is bound to slow things down.

Local memory can deliver performance benefits in certain scenarios, when applied carefully. In many cases however, the hardware caches will do a better job, and leave you with much simpler code.